# Parsing xlsx sheet from HTTP response using openpyxl library

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

I am writing a test case for testing Excel sheet parsing. 
I tried to parse the response.content into list of objects using openpyxl.
I have extracted the filename from response header and converted into File like object. load_workbook() is not accepting the filename.

```
def test_export_timesheet(self):
        change_url = '/admin/core/timesheet/'

        #response contains the generated file using openpyxl
        response = self.client.post(change_url, {'action': 'export_xlsx', '_selected_action': [x.id for x in timesheets]})

    content = response._headers.get('content-disposition')[1]
    start = content.find('=') + 1
    end = content.find('.xlsx')
    content_path = (content[start:end]+'.xlsx')

    #Passing file like object
    wb = load_workbook(BytesIO(filename="'"+content_path+"'"))
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name="'" + content[start:end] + "'")
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            print cell.value
```

Basically I am trying to validate the contents of the file in my testcase. 
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think openpyxl plays nice with the byte stream.  You may have to save it to a temp file, call load_workbook with the temp file, then delete the temp file once you are done.

Comment: As Rob says it's best to use a real file. Note, there is no need to use the filename from the response. Just dump the file in a known-writable folder and pass the pass to openpyxl. This will also allow you to decouple anything you do with the file from your http-request cycle.

Comment: Thanks @RobDavis. That worked for me. 

Here is the code 

       `new_file = open('/tmp/timesheet-1.xlsx', 'w')
        new_file.write(response.content)
        new_file.close()
        wb = load_workbook('/tmp/timesheet-1.xlsx')
        ws = wb.get_active_sheet()`

Answer (score 1):

```
# response contains the generated file using openpyxl
response = self.client.post(change_url, ・・・・・
```

When you get the response above, "response.content" is bytes-type, so you can load it into the buffer with BytesIO. Continuing from above, write:

```
from io import BytesIO
file_like_object = BytesIO(response.content)
(from openpyxl import load_workbook) # if this line is needed...
wb = load_workbook(file_like_object)
```

Now you can use this "wb" for general openpyxl operations